# SetTimeout is failing in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout

I want increment the count for every second. so i am using do while loop but it is crashing the browser.

code:

```
do{
   $scope.timer = 0;
   console.log($scope.timer);
   setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.timer = $scope.timer+1;
        return $scope.timer; });
    }, 1000);
  }while($scope.timer < $scope.level._seconds_per_question);
```

Could any suggest where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can u please give the full controller code...

Comment: @parthicool05 , I am using this code in inside of interval function. There is nothing more than this code. I am failing here it self.

Comment: Friend where did u write this code it is inside of the controller or not..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is a native Angular service - [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) which allows you to do timeouts without having to call `$scope.$apply`.

So, you could do something like this:

```
function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.timer = 0;
    $scope.level = {
      // I assume this object is declared in a parent $scope in your code.
      // I define it here just so the sample will work.
      _seconds_per_question: 10
    };

    $timeout(increment, 1000);

    function increment() {
        if ($scope.timer < $scope.level._seconds_per_question) {
          console.log($scope.timer);
            $scope.timer ++;
            $timeout(increment, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/CAfwGRa5M1BmBC3s8cKa?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Please find below the code**

```
function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) 
{
  $scope.timeInMs = 0;  
  var countUp = function() {
    $scope.timeInMs+= 1;
    $timeout(countUp, 1000);
  }    
  $timeout(countUp, 1000);
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/archanagw2010/fq4vg/776/

Comment: @CaspNZ: **I have modified the code as well as i have created the jsfiddle for this**

Comment: @Archana, Could you tell where is that jsfiddle link?

Comment: @Anusha: Cannot you see my above shared jsfiddle link along with my answer?[sample]http://jsfiddle.net/archanagw2010/fq4vg/776/ Can you please let me know either you can access that or not?

Comment: @Archana, Sorry page is not refreshed before